# When using Computed variable and Snapkit: No common superview between views

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, snapkit

So here's the thing, I'm declaring a property like this:

```
var aNameLabel: UILabel {
    guard let foo = Applicant.sharedInstance.realName else {
        return UILabel(text: "获取姓名失败", color: .whiteColor())
    }
    return UILabel(text: foo, color: .whiteColor())
}
```

And when I try to add constraint to the aNameLabel after I did `someView.addSubView(aNameLabel)`, the app would crash every time at this constraint-adding thing, and says `No common superview between views`

However, when I change the variable into a let constant like this:

`let aNameLabel = UILabel(text: "Allen", color: .whiteColor())`

The constraint will be added with no complaint. Somebody can help me with this?

## UPDATE

With the help of @par , I've changed my code into this:

```
var aNameLabel: UILabel = {
    guard let foo = Applicant.sharedInstance.realName else {
        return UILabel(text: "BAD", color: .whiteColor())
    }
    return UILabel(text: foo, color: .whiteColor())
}()
```

And then the `aNameLabel` would always be assigned with value "BAD", while actually my `guard let` is successful. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new `UILabel` every time you access the `aNameLabel` variable (a computed property function runs every time you access it).  Presumably you are doing the same thing for the superview of this view (when you access `someView` in `someView.addSubview()` in your example above).  If so, that's why there's no common superview and you are crashing.

You should create only one instance of each `UIView` used by your view controller, so creating a variable as a constant as you've shown *is* a great approach, or you can use a closure-initializer pattern like so:

```
var aNameLabel: UILabel = {
    return UILabel(...)
}()
```

Notice in the above example the parentheses after the closing brace.  Because it's a closure-initializer it will only be called once just like a `let` constant.

Often a `UIView` created with `let` isn't appropriate because constant properties need to be initialized before `init()` returns, and if you're creating views in a view controller you won't have a chance to add views until `loadView()` is called.  In this case, declare your `UIView`s as implicitly-unwrapped optionals.  They will be set to `nil` by `init()` which meets the initialization requirement, then you can set them to actual views later when `viewDidLoad()` is called, for example:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var someSubview: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        someSubview = UIView()
        view.addSubview(someSubview)
        // now set constraints with SnapKit
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mate! This really helped! But I've still got a problem about this. Please read my question update.

Comment: Hi I just chose to initialize the value in `viewDidLoad()`. Problem's solved. I just wanted my `viewDidLoad()` to be simpler and to assign the values to the variable right when they're being declared.